# How to use a boolean with two meanings within an if, nested if, else statement

Tags: java

Ok, So when I run the code, after typing in no or anything that which is false, my program doesn't jump to the Else statement at the bottom (Outside of the nested if_Else statement) What am I doing wrong? I tried initiating it with else if (yes!=true) or Else (!yes), I mean you name it, including changing the initial arguments and imputing ( yes==true ^ no==true) however, defining another boolean variable to no and set to true as well!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Flights
{
    public static void main(String args[]){
    String txt;
    boolean yes=true;

    Scanner type=new Scanner(System.in);
    int days;

    System.out.println("Is this a round trip? ");
    txt=type.next();

        if(yes==true){
            System.out.println("How many days in advance do you plan to book your flight?: ");
            days=type.nextInt(); 
            if(days>180)        
                System.out.println("Error: Flights can't be booked for more than 180 days out");    

            else if( days<=180 && days>=14)
                System.out.println("Your flight cost is: $275");

            else if(days<14 && days>=7)
                System.out.println(" Your flight cost is: $320");

            else if(days<7)
                System.out.println("Your flight cost is: $440");
                     }
        else
           {
                System.out.println("Enter your discount code");

           }                


    }
}
```

Comment: You never changed the value of `yes` based on the input! It will always equal true if you don't change it.

Comment: Do you mean, setting the outside else to the following: else if (yes!=true){S.O.P();}\

Comment: Thank you very much everyone!...I appreciate the help!...Nguyen Tuan Anh's method worked!!! Now I just need to understand what the hell those words mean lol. I LOVE CODING!...but damn it's going to take some time!...

Comment: LAST! based on this inquiry, I noticed many of you gave answer including, txt.equalsIgnore, txt.qualsLowerCase etc...what are these called? and what in your opinion is a great book or textbook for me to learn these key elements to simplify my coding life!

Comment: The best source is the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). That is the documentation for the `String` class. If you scroll through it, you will find every method (they are called methods) which you can call on a string object. If you google the name of a class, you can find all of the methods available for that class by going to the documentation.

Comment: It helps lowercase your input string, so you will not need to repeat the comparison like "Yes".equals(txt) || "yEs".equals(txt) || "yeS".equals(txt) || "YES".equals(txt) || ... You got it?

Comment: again I can't thank you enough brother!...thanks for the info. I'm in lab, I'm literally about to scrutinize the documentation doc.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you initiate the `yes` variable to `true`, and didn't update it whatsoever before you start the conditional statement where you compare the value of `yes` to `true`. That's the issue.

This is where you begin:

```
boolean yes=true;
```

and then you wait for user typing in, but do not update the `yes` value, instead, you go ahead and check it like this.

```
if(yes==true){
}
```

This results in the else statement will never be reached.

---

What you could do is, following this line:

```
txt=type.next();
```

You can update the value of the `yes` variable, something like this:

```
txt=type.next();  
yes = (txt != null) && "yes".equals(txt.toLowerCase());

if(yes==true){
    //...
} else {
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

For your program to make a decision based on the user input, you have to look at the value of `txt`.

Change your code to something like this:

```
yes = txt.equalsIgnoreCase("yes");
if (yes == true) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

Or even shorter:

```
if (txt.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```